# PHP Connection Erreur : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed

Tags: php, mysql, database

It's the first time I ask a question on a forum.

I'm making a quizz with a basic html form and need to save the answers on my server (using lcn.com company for hosting it). 
Server details:
Host: database3.lcn.com
User: xxx
pwd: xxx

Alright, I'm simply trying to connect to my MySQL database using PHP language.
I've pasted here my php file:

```
<?php
        $dsn='mysql:host=database3.lcn.com;dbname=test_table;charset=utf8';
        $user="***";
        $pwd="***";

        try {
            $linkpdo = new PDO ($dsn,$user,$pwd);

            echo "Success!";

            $linkpdo=null;
        } catch(Exception $e) {

            die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());

        }
?>
```

But I have this problem :
Erreur : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

And don't know why it doesn't work...

Could someone please give me a hand?

Thanks

Comment: it means that either the host database3.lcn.com cannot be reached on the default mysql port of 3306.

Comment: So, what can I do? Can I change the default port?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.1 - SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[2002\] A connection attempt failed.. - When attempting to connect from Local to remote server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36914770/laravel-5-1-sqlstatehy000-2002-a-connection-attempt-failed-when-attemp)

Answer (score -1):

mysql --version

sudo service mysql restart

sudo mysql

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.