# Laravel connecting to remote mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, shared-hosting

I'm trying to connect to my remote mysql database (*infinityfree.net*) in my Laravel (*Version 5.6*) application. This is my configuration in **database.php** file:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => 'sql201.epizy.com',
        'database' => 'epiz_22148680_LaravelHospital',
        'username' => 'epiz_22148680',
        'password' => 'Vxp7****R1k6',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
```

I also changed the **.env** file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=sql201.epizy.com
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=epiz_22148680_LaravelHospital
DB_USERNAME=epiz_22148680
DB_PASSWORD=Vxp7****R1k6
```

However, when I try to connect to my database I get this error:

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a p
>   period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36914770/sqlstatehy000-2002-a-connection-attempt-failed-when-attempting-to-connec) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47021870/sqlstatehy000-2002-a-connection-attempt-failed-because-the-connected-party-d?noredirect=1&lq=1) but they were not answered.

Comment: probably same question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29849852/php-connection-erreur-sqlstatehy000-2002-a-connection-attempt-failed

Comment: I'm sure my config is correct. I mean, the database name, host name,etc.

Comment: First of all, you have never to declare users and passwords in the config file, use `env('KEY', 'default value if key not found')` and then the `.env` file will be used. Second, from what you are posting, it seems the port is not opened from the remote server. Try to connect from your PC with a DB Sofware of from terminal with `telnet IP PORT` and if that telnet connects, then it is opened, if not, well...

Comment: I've tried two different hosting website, but I get the same error. I tried telnet too. It doesn't connect

Comment: it thinks you can not connect to remote MySQL in `demo` mode. check `Remote MySQL` section in your `CPanel`

Answer (score 0):

By default, remote access to the MySQL database server is disabled for security reasons.
MySQL instance is only configured to listen for local connections. This is MySQL’s default setting, but it won’t work for a remote database setup since MySQL must be able to listen for an external IP address where the server can be reached.

To enable this, open up your mysqld.cnf file:

look for the following line,

```
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

for the purpose of troubleshooting change it to 0.0.0.0.

restart MySQL and check the connection again.

if its working change 0.0.0.0 to yourWEBSERVERIPaddress

if you have any problems here is the complete tutorial.

https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Comment: Also not when you are setting up credentials that they must not be set to localhost.